# Angular.js with PHP MVC (Codeigniter) confusions

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to build SPA web app with Angular.js, however it will use Codeigniter MVC on the server side.

I am confused because to follow the Codeigniter MVC rules all views should be under application/views folder and those should be accessible by calling an controller method which will return view. I read about angular angular.js structure and I think the solution [described here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) is very good. However, following this structure all views excluding index should be in public html/app/module_name/ folder.

I am wondering where html views should go? To public HTML or to application/views folder and what is the difference, how it could affect my further app?

I hope that I described my problem well enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't need codeigniter to deliver views .. just extra overhead vs serving html file directly. Backend is usually just used for api. Start by thinking of codeigniter and angular as 2 separate entities

Comment: what about the "security" is there a difference if all people even if they are not logged in will have access to all views which will be stored in public folder and they can see more structure of the app?

Comment: If you didn't want anyone looking at any html you could deliver them through framework, but is usually not that big a deal since data would be not delivered if not logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codeIgniter multi views load are not for SPA (Single page application), 
angularJS is for SPA, what you need to do is load a single PHP page from  codeiginter and use partials with [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) or directives.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('main');
}
```

main.php:

```
<div ng-include="pathToHTMlView.html"></div>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```